# Asymmetric eta square matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a function that calculates the eta square coefficient for the correlation between qualitative and quantitative variable:

```
eta <- function(x,y){
  m <- mean(x,na.rm = TRUE)
  sct <- sum((x-m)^2,na.rm = TRUE)
  n <- table(y)
  mk <- tapply(x,y,mean)
  sce <- sum(n*(mk-m)^2)
  return(ifelse(sct>0,sce/sct,0))
}
```

Imagine I have the following variables (just an example), with missing values in it:

```
a <-  factor(c("M","NA","F","F","NA","M","F"))
b <-  factor(c("y","y","y","n","n","n","y")
d <- c(2,5,4,8,9,6,4)
e <- c(5,7,8,5,6,9,7)
```

I need to program a function that returns a matrix with the eta coefficient for each combination of qualitative and quantitative variable x and y.
Something like this maybe (it doesnt work):

```
 matrix<-function(x,y){
  col.y<-ncol(y)
  row.x<-nrow(x)
  M<-matrix(ncol=col.y,nrow=row.x,dimnames = list(names(x), names(y)))
  for(i in 1:col.y){
    for(j in 1:row.x){
      M[i,j]<-rap.corr(y[,i],x[,j])
    }
  }
  return(M)
}
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance..

Comment: how do you want to build your matrix from `a`, `b`, `d`, `e` ? In one word, what's your expected output? (just the general form, the figures in the matrix do no matter)

Comment: A correlation matrix with the qualitative variables a and b  on one side and the the quantitative variables in the columns. I have missing values in the variables. It should be an aymmetric matrix when there are more qualitative than quantitative variables for instance

Comment: With `a` and `b` on one side?? Do you mean the number of `rows` is equal to 2 and the number of cols equals to 2 so that the matrix contains `eta(a,e)`, `eta(a,d)`, `eta(b,e)` and `eta(b,d)`?

Comment: Yes right, I mean the number of `rows` depends on the number of quantitative variables. for this example its 2.

Comment: Ok, here is an approach below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `mapply`:

```
qual = list(a=a, b=b)
quant = list(e=e,d=d)

m = matrix(mapply(eta, rep(quant, length(qual)), rep(qual, each=length(quant))), ncol=length(qual))

rownames(m) = names(quant)
colnames(m) = names(qual)

#> m
#           a            b
#e 0.01950355 0.0008865248
#d 0.25333333 0.7363333333
```

Comment: Wow, thats easier than I thought! No loops with mapply!

Comment: Some beauty of functional programming! The trick is mostly in `rep(x, each=length(y))` and `rep(y, length(x))` !